# Vue js 3 remove debugger and console log from Production

Tags: vue.js, production

So i'm using vue js 3 and vue.config.js.

and this is what i have tried:

```
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      minimizer: isProd
        ? [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
              uglifyOptions: {
                compress: {
                  drop_debugger: true,
                  drop_console: true,
                },
                // sourceMap: true,
                // comments: false,
              },
            }),
          ]
        : [],
    },
  },
```

And it's working! But for some reason it doesn't show router-link and what is inside my router link:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'project', params: {id: data.id.value}}">
                                <el-button type="primary">
                                    <i class="fa el-icon-fa-sign-in"></i>
                                </el-button>
                            </router-link>
```

if i remove router link and use

```
<span>Then it will show my span</span>
```

Can you help me please to fix issue with the router-link when i'm running UglifyJsPlugin?

Do you know another way how can i remove debugger and console log from Production?

Comment: Uglify is obsolete. Terser has to be used. Since it's already used in production build, it makes sense to configure it instead of putting another minifier into the toolchain. See https://cli.vuejs.org/migrating-from-v3/#vue-cli-service

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/335
This is solved my issue, Thank you for your help :)